# Using win32service module with IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, pywin32

Hey,so I'm trying to take an existing IronPython script I have and convert it into a windows service that runs on one of our servers at all times. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the modules I need. I downloaded the pywin32 extensions (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) but I can't install them because I only have IronPython installed on this server, and not the vanilla 2.6 interpreter. Thanks to anyone who can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use pywin32 to create a Windows Service with IronPython. If an IronPython Windows Service is what you want, this project might help:
http://dlrhostservice.codeplex.com/

Good Luck!

Comment: when would you use `IronPython` (.NET based interface) over `pywin32/comtypes` (COM based interface). It seems `.NET` is supposed to superced COM, but `pywin32/comtypes` is way more mature and more usedd in reality..